# What was this religious-themed RPG from 90s/2000s about a war between heaven and hell to get souls as fast as possible?

Tags: religions-and-deities, product-identification

I'm trying to remember the name of a tabletop RPG I once ran across. This was a religious-themed game in the early 2000s, or possibly the late 90s.

The only thing I can really remember is that there is a war between heaven and hell to get souls as fast as possible since the rapture is coming. There is a drug that makes people see god and if you get addicted to it it gives your soul to the side of heaven. The biggest dealer of this drug is Jesus. There is one image I can remember from the book that is Jesus in a speedboat; he may have been wearing sunglasses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the RPG I was thinking of: [Heaven & Earth (2nd Edition)](https://rpggeek.com/rpg/1687/heaven-earth-2nd-edition)

Comment: You should expand your answer to support it by explaining what elements of the linked RPG match the details you remembered that are listed in the question. That way, your Q&A can be more useful to others who find it in the future.